# Dropdownlist in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, html.dropdownlistfor

How to link two dropdown lists with same local db but when same value is selected in the two dropdownlists it shows an error message.

Answer (score 0):

assuming that you have `ComboBox1` and `ComboBox2`. what simple thing you can do is to create a `bool method` that would validate if these two `Controls` have the same value and fire it on the `SelectedIndexChaged` event of both Controls.

```
private bool IsComboBoxSameValue()
{
    if(ComboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() == ComboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("The ComboBoxes have the same value");
        return true; // the ComboBoxes has the same value
    }
    else
    {
        return false; // the comboboxes has different value
    }
}
```

use it like:

```
ComboBox1_SelectedItemChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(IsComboBoxSameValue())
        return;

    // do long running work here after you validated that the ComboBoxes have different value
}
```